# Using max function in Oracle to find a record

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, subquery

Ok, so I've got two tables in Oracle:

CAR, with attribute owner (references EMPLOYEE(ssn))

EMPLOYEE, with attributes name, ssn.

I need to get the name and ssn of the employee with the maximum number of cars, but I'm having trouble understanding how to use aggregate functions in this manner...

I've tried something like the following:

```
    SELECT name, ssn
    FROM EMPLOYEE
    WHERE ssn IN (SELECT owner
                  FROM CAR
                  HAVING COUNT(owner) = MAX(COUNT(owner))
                  GROUP BY owner)
```

But it's not seeming to return anything...am I even on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select e.name,e.ssn,count(*)
from EMPLOYEE e 
inner join CAR c on e.ssn = c.owner
group by e.name,e.ssn
```

Comment: This would merely return all employees with at least one car, and calculate the number of cars for each employee - would need to do a sort at least to fully answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from EMPLOYEE
where ssn = (
  select min(owner) keep (dense_rank first order by count(1) desc, owner) 
  from CAR 
  group by owner
)
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8762a/2)

Comment: It looks like your code works, but could you elaborate on what's going on here?

Comment: This would work just as well if you removed EMPLOYEE from the subquery.